# a native javascript addon cannot make it run on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am new to javascript stuff, I am trying to use a native addons and I got it compiled and tested using node under console. However when it is included in the html and run under chrome, it keeps saying require is not defined. Then I use browserify to bundle it, but I got this message:

Parse Error: Unexpected character '?'

index.js:

```
const Input = require('./build/release/sendinput.node');
console.log('test',Input);
function SendInput(inputs){
    if(!Array.isArray(inputs))
        inputs = [inputs];
    let arr = [];
    for(let inp of inputs){
        if(typeof inp != "object")
            throw new Error("Expecting array of objects");
        if(!Number.isInteger(inp.type) || inp.type < 0 || inp.type > 2)
            throw new Error("Expecting type to be an integer from 0 to 2");
        if(!Number.isInteger(inp.val))
            throw new Error("Expecting val to be an integer")
        switch(inp.type){
            case 0:
                arr.push(Input.CreateKBDInpVKey(inp.val, !!inp.up));
            break;
            case 1:
                let val = inp.val;
                let extended = false;
                if(val >> 8 & 0xFF == 0xe0)
                    extended = true;
                arr.push(Input.CreateKBDInpScanCode(inp.val & 0xFF, !!inp.up, extended));
            break;
            case 2:
                arr.push(Input.CreateKBDInpUnicode(inp.val, !!inp.up));
            break;
        }
    }
    return Input.SendInput(arr);
}
module.exports = {SendInput}  //SendInput now a object.
```

by running: node index.js, the output is:

```
test {
  SendInput: [Function],
  CreateKBDInpVKey: [Function],
  CreateKBDInpScanCode: [Function],
  CreateKBDInpUnicode: [Function]
}
```

I need to let them work on the browser. Anyone can give me some help on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can not use native node modules on browsers, that's it.
you may run a Nodejs rest server, and use rest calls from a browser to server and let the Nodejs do the job and use the response on browsers that's it.

Comment: Thanks, after I did some research, I understand what you are talking. I saw someone recommend to compile emscripten to compile c++ natives into javascript and then runon web browser, does this make sense? Thanks

Comment: that module made to work as a "node native module" it's using maybe N-API, v8, and other things, to compile it as "web assembly", you need to rewrite that module and then compile.